# Should I use a Dictionary for collections with 10 items or less, or is there a better alternative?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, collections, dictionary

I have a list of objects and I need to find an object as quickly as possible (by it's name property). What data-structure should I use? I know I can use a Dictionary, but there wont ever be more than 10 items in the list, and if I remember correctly the dictionary is implemented as an array if the collection contains 10 items or less.

Thanks.

Comment: For 10 items or less it probably wouldn't matter what type of structure you use.

Comment: The choice of data structure depends on a lot of factors other than just size. How often are the elements going to be inserted and removed? How critical is the speed in finding an object? Is this going to be used in a tight loop? How critical is the speed of insertions and removals? Is 10 items a hard limit, or a ballpark?

Comment: Have you profiled your application and determined this to be a performance bottleneck? I would be very surprised if it were.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic - it won't matter for theoretical time complexity but it might very well matter for practical performance. There could be millions of operations like that, obviously guy is not concerned with having it running just once. Neither is anyone reading this question many years from the time it was posted, like myself.

Comment: @julkiewicz then you already know your answer, array, the answer is array there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MSDN recommends the [ListDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.listdictionary.aspx) for collections with 10 items or less:

> This is a simple implementation of IDictionary using a singly linked list. It is smaller and faster than a Hashtable if the number of elements is 10 or less. This should not be used if performance is important for large numbers of elements.

Comment: That recommendation might be out of date since ListDictionary is not generic. The docs have said that since the beginning.

Comment: Thank you Anna, that seems to be a perfect answer to my question.

Answer (score 7):

You may want to consider the `System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary` if you are certain there will be less than ten items.

Also consider the `System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary` which switches behaviour (with a small overhead) should the size increase above a threshold, handy if your assumption is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want fastest possible lookup by a property you should use `Dictionary<Key, Value>`. The size doesn't hurt you if you want fast lookup. It's not that a `Dictionary<Key, Value>` of just 10 items or less is taking up a ton of memory. `Dictionary<Key, Value>` has a constructor that takes an int to set the capacity.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a Hashtable?  It's in the System.Collections namespace.

Comment: Because both the Dictionary<> and Hashtable classes are implementations of hashtables and have an overhead in having to calculate the hashcode for each item which only pays for itself when the collection is not trivially small.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, `KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>` will do. It is a hybrid structure, the constructor takes a parameter to denote from what size onward the structure should switch from linear list to a hash based lookup. And yes it is generic.

One downside is it is an abstract class, so you will have to derive one yourself.

```
public class KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem> : System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>
{
    private readonly Func<TItem, TKey> m_keySelector;

    public KeyedCollection(Func<TItem, TKey> keySelector)
        : this(keySelector, null)
    {
    }

    public KeyedCollection(Func<TItem, TKey> keySelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
        : this(keySelector, comparer, 10)
    {
    }

    public KeyedCollection(Func<TItem, TKey> keySelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer, int dictionaryCreationThreshold)
        : base(comparer, dictionaryCreationThreshold)
    {
        m_keySelector = keySelector;
    }

    protected override TKey GetKeyForItem(TItem item)
    {
        return m_keySelector(item);
    }
}
```

Then you could call it:

```
var foo = new KeyedCollection<Foo, string>(f => f.Name, null, 10);
```