# C# - From what collection size should I start using Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, performance, dictionary, coding-efficiency

I was surprised I couldn't find an answer to this.
So I know a Dictionary does look-ups in O(1) asymptotically but with a hashing overhead. Is there like a rule of thumb for a collection size under which a List is preferable to a Dictionary? Tens of items? hundreds? Thousands?

Comment: I cannot provide evidence but you should start using dictionaries like when you have 20 items

Comment: A list search will indeed take O(n), but there are other considerations here than collection size and time; what are you intending to do your lookups by (i.e. the Key type for the Dictionary)? Is it an Equatable type that's immutable once constructed? Some property of the items you're storing that can change while the item is in the collection? The answers to these can make Dictionary impractical, or require additional handling to ensure it works as you expect; can you provide specifics of what you're looking to optimise?

Comment: This in fact exists in the framework, System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary class.  Useful back in the .NET 1.x days, it automatically switches over from a list to a hash table if it has enough items.  Not repeated at .NET 2.0 when generics became available, it wasn't necessary.  Because the micro-optimization it provided was cutting down on storage overhead, not compute overhead.  If you have a broken GetHashCode() then perf is always going suffer badly when it matters most, when you have too many items.

Comment: The use case is so much more important. Write readable code. Because this only  applies to small datasets it can only be a micro optimization.

Comment: I don't understand why it has been down-voted. It is a legitimate question. When do we need to start using O(1) for searching? I agreed with dlxeon (answer below). I agreed that it depends on the situation, but to provide a guideline on 'general' situation is appropriate.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419580/should-i-use-a-dictionary-for-collections-with-10-items-or-less-or-is-there-a-b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, tipping point is between 10 - 50 items, depending on usage pattern and complexity of your hash function. But you should do benchmark on your data, especially if your custom hash function can take a while to calculate cache.

You can also use `HybridDictionary` that is internally a List for small amount of entries and Hash table after that. .Net framework source [shows](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/specialized/hybriddictionary.cs,46493f5a763cebe1) cutover point at 9 items.

```
    public class HybridDictionary: IDictionary {

    // These numbers have been carefully tested to be optimal. Please don't change them
    // without doing thorough performance testing.
    private const int CutoverPoint = 9;
    private const int InitialHashtableSize = 13;
    private const int FixedSizeCutoverPoint = 6;
```

**Update**: as @Hans Passant pointed out in comment above, Hybrid dictionary doesn't have generic version which can affect performance for boxing/unboxing and overall usage. So, you should be careful and do benchmarks for your situation. My point was to show, that something about ~10 items can be a point to start using dictionary vs list.